# dynamic table in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Idea behind this code is some personal thinking on some feature that may be useful for all members to be having record of details.

```
const schoolTimings = [
  {
    schoolType: 'Primary School',
    list: [
      {
        school: 'ABC',
        day: 'Monday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '12:30'
      },
      {
        school: 'ABC',
        day: 'Tuesday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '12:30'
      },
      {
        school: 'ABC',
        day: 'Thursday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '12:30'
      },
      {
        school: 'ABC',
        day: 'Friday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '12:30'
      },
      {
        school: 'ABC',
        day: 'Saturday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '12:30'
      },
      {
        school: 'XYZ',
        day: 'Monday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '12:00'
      },
      {
        school: 'XYZ',
        day: 'Tuesday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '12:00'
      },
      {
        school: 'XYZ',
        day: 'Wednesday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '12:00'
      },
      {
        school: 'XYZ',
        day: 'Thursday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '12:00'
      },
      {
        school: 'XYZ',
        day: 'Friday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '12:00'
      },
      {
        school: 'XYZ',
        day: 'Saturday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '12:00'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    schoolType: 'Secondary School',
    list: [
      {
        school: 'PQR',
        day: 'Monday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '15:30'
      },
      {
        school: 'PQR',
        day: 'Tuesday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '15:30'
      },
      {
        school: 'PQR',
        day: 'Wednesday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '15:30'
      },
      {
        school: 'PQR',
        day: 'Thursday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '15:30'
      },
      {
        school: 'PQR',
        day: 'Friday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '15:30'
      },
      {
        school: 'PQR',
        day: 'Saturday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '15:30'
      },
      {
        school: 'XYZ',
        day: 'Monday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '17:00'
      },
      {
        school: 'XYZ',
        day: 'Tuesday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '17:00'
      },
      {
        school: 'XYZ',
        day: 'Wednesday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '17:00'
      },
      {
        school: 'XYZ',
        day: 'Thursday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '17:00'
      },
      {
        school: 'XYZ',
        day: 'Friday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '17:00'
      },
      {
        school: 'XYZ',
        day: 'Saturday',
        open: '08:00',
        close: '17:00'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

All the data provided is imaginary , not exact data .

> I am trying this for past 1 month , unable to get  output,

need in **reactjs with js or typescript** with the format as pic attached (for reference)
[image: Output for above data format needed as shown in this screenshot.]

Please do share answer if you know the solution, Thank You to whole helping community.

Comment: Please share what you tried so far and explain what issues are you facing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code works for what you ask:

```js
import React from 'react';

const Tab = () => {

    const schoolTimings = [
        {
            schoolType: 'Primary School',
            list: [
                {
                    school: 'ABC',
                    day: 'Monday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '12:30'
                },
                {
                    school: 'ABC',
                    day: 'Tuesday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '12:30'
                },
                {
                    school: 'ABC',
                    day: 'Thursday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '12:30'
                },
                {
                    school: 'ABC',
                    day: 'Friday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '12:30'
                },
                {
                    school: 'ABC',
                    day: 'Saturday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '12:30'
                },
                {
                    school: 'XYZ',
                    day: 'Monday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '12:00'
                },
                {
                    school: 'XYZ',
                    day: 'Tuesday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '12:00'
                },
                {
                    school: 'XYZ',
                    day: 'Wednesday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '12:00'
                },
                {
                    school: 'XYZ',
                    day: 'Thursday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '12:00'
                },
                {
                    school: 'XYZ',
                    day: 'Friday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '12:00'
                },
                {
                    school: 'XYZ',
                    day: 'Saturday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '12:00'
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            schoolType: 'Secondary School',
            list: [
                {
                    school: 'PQR',
                    day: 'Monday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '15:30'
                },
                {
                    school: 'PQR',
                    day: 'Tuesday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '15:30'
                },
                {
                    school: 'PQR',
                    day: 'Wednesday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '15:30'
                },
                {
                    school: 'PQR',
                    day: 'Thursday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '15:30'
                },
                {
                    school: 'PQR',
                    day: 'Friday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '15:30'
                },
                {
                    school: 'PQR',
                    day: 'Saturday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '15:30'
                },
                {
                    school: 'XYZ',
                    day: 'Monday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '17:00'
                },
                {
                    school: 'XYZ',
                    day: 'Tuesday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '17:00'
                },
                {
                    school: 'XYZ',
                    day: 'Wednesday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '17:00'
                },
                {
                    school: 'XYZ',
                    day: 'Thursday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '17:00'
                },
                {
                    school: 'XYZ',
                    day: 'Friday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '17:00'
                },
                {
                    school: 'XYZ',
                    day: 'Saturday',
                    open: '08:00',
                    close: '17:00'
                }
            ]
        }
    ];

    let table2 = <></>
    for (let i = 0; i < schoolTimings.length; i++) {
        table2 = <>{table2}
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colSpan="15"  style={{color: "blue", fontWeight: "bold"}}>  {schoolTimings[i].schoolType}  </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </>;
        let listSchool = []
        for (let j = 0; j < schoolTimings[i].list.length; j++) {
            if (listSchool.indexOf(schoolTimings[i].list[j].school) === -1) {
                listSchool.push(schoolTimings[i].list[j].school)
            }
        }
        for (let k = 0; k < listSchool.length; k++) {
            let listValueSchool = {
                School: listSchool[k],
                Monday: {
                    open: '',
                    close: ''
                },
                Tuesday: {
                    open: '',
                    close: ''
                }, Wednesday: {
                    open: '',
                    close: ''
                }, Thursday: {
                    open: '',
                    close: ''
                }, Friday: {
                    open: '',
                    close: ''
                }, Saturday: {
                    open: '',
                    close: ''
                }, Sunday: {
                    open: '',
                    close: ''
                },
            }
            for (let j = 0; j < schoolTimings[i].list.length; j++) {
                if (schoolTimings[i].list[j].school === listSchool[k]) {
                    switch (schoolTimings[i].list[j].day) {
                        case 'Monday':
                            listValueSchool.Monday = {
                                open: schoolTimings[i].list[j].open,
                                close: schoolTimings[i].list[j].close
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'Tuesday':
                            listValueSchool.Tuesday = {
                                open: schoolTimings[i].list[j].open,
                                close: schoolTimings[i].list[j].close
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'Wednesday':
                            listValueSchool.Wednesday = {
                                open: schoolTimings[i].list[j].open,
                                close: schoolTimings[i].list[j].close
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'Thursday':
                            listValueSchool.Thursday = {
                                open: schoolTimings[i].list[j].open,
                                close: schoolTimings[i].list[j].close
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'Friday':
                            listValueSchool.Friday = {
                                open: schoolTimings[i].list[j].open,
                                close: schoolTimings[i].list[j].close
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'Saturday':
                            listValueSchool.Saturday = {
                                open: schoolTimings[i].list[j].open,
                                close: schoolTimings[i].list[j].close
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'Sunday':
                            listValueSchool.Sunday = {
                                open: schoolTimings[i].list[j].open,
                                close: schoolTimings[i].list[j].close
                            }
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            table2 = <>{table2}
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>{listValueSchool.School}</td>
                    <td>{listValueSchool.Sunday.open}</td>
                    <td>{listValueSchool.Sunday.close}</td>
                    <td>{listValueSchool.Monday.open}</td>
                    <td>{listValueSchool.Monday.close}</td>
                    <td>{listValueSchool.Tuesday.open}</td>
                    <td>{listValueSchool.Tuesday.close}</td>
                    <td>{listValueSchool.Wednesday.open}</td>
                    <td>{listValueSchool.Wednesday.close}</td>
                    <td>{listValueSchool.Thursday.open}</td>
                    <td>{listValueSchool.Thursday.close}</td>
                    <td>{listValueSchool.Friday.open}</td>
                    <td>{listValueSchool.Friday.close}</td>
                    <td>{listValueSchool.Saturday.open}</td>
                    <td>{listValueSchool.Saturday.close}</td>

                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </>;
        }


    }


    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>

                <th colSpan="1" style={{color: "purple"}}>Day</th>
                <th colSpan="2" style={{color: "purple"}}>Sunday</th>
                <th colSpan="2" style={{color: "purple"}}>Monday</th>
                <th colSpan="2" style={{color: "purple"}}>Tuesday</th>
                <th colSpan="2" style={{color: "purple"}}>Wednesday</th>
                <th colSpan="2" style={{color: "purple"}}>Thursday</th>
                <th colSpan="2" style={{color: "purple"}}>Friday</th>
                <th colSpan="2" style={{color: "purple"}}>Saturday</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td colSpan="1">School</td>
                <td colSpan="1">Open</td>
                <td colSpan="1">Close</td>
                <td colSpan="1">Open</td>
                <td colSpan="1">Close</td>
                <td colSpan="1">Open</td>
                <td colSpan="1">Close</td>
                <td colSpan="1">Open</td>
                <td colSpan="1">Close</td>
                <td colSpan="1">Open</td>
                <td colSpan="1">Close</td>
                <td colSpan="1">Open</td>
                <td colSpan="1">Close</td>
                <td colSpan="1">Open</td>
                <td colSpan="1">Close</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
            {table2}
        </table>
    );
}

export default Tab;
```

Comment: Thank You Lucas very much , this helps me maintain some data of my friends by my age wise and will share same if its useful to community if final product is good and working as I wanted .